# JLabel is painted twice

Tags: java, swing

Before I begin, let my say that I am very new to Java. I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

So, I've created a JFrame, loaded an image as an ImageIcon, and turned that into a JLabel, which I added to the Frame. Problem was, it was a pain to control the size and position of the label.

I found this solution:

```
        final ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(loadFrames.class.getResource("/images/testimage.png"));


    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image){

        @Override
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent (g);
                if (image != null) {
                    g.drawImage (image.getImage(), 300, 0, image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight(), null);
                }
            }
        };

        gameFrame.add(imageLabel);  

        imageLabel.setVisible(true);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
```

As you can see, I found a response online that showed the usages of the Graphics object. I don't know how it works or why it works, but it does. The problem is, the image is drawn twice. Once in the original spot (in the center) and once at the (300,0).

Thanks for any feedback on how to stop it from drawing it at the original location. If you know an easier way to adjust the size and position of a label, say that as well. I'm not using a LayoutManager.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You supplied the `JLabel` with a `ImageIcon`...

```
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image)
```

But then override it's `paintComponent` method and painted it manually...

```
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g);
            if (image != null) {
                g.drawImage (image.getImage(), 300, 0, image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight(), null);
            }
        }
    };
```

...Not really sure what you were expected to happen...

`JLabel` is the default way to show images.

When calling `drawImage`, you should pass `this` as the `ImageObserver`, which all Swing components implement, especially when using `ImageIcon` to load images, as the image may not have completed loading by the time the component is first painted.  Using `this` as the `ImageObserver` allows the component to schedule repaints automatically when the state of the image loading changes

Perhaps you should have a closer look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: I found the reason it was being painted twice.

`super.paintComponent (g);`

Like I said, I'm a noob. label.setSize and setLocation were doing nothing.

Comment: @JohnPicco Dear god no!  The reason it's painting twice is `g.drawImage`!!  You MUST always call `super.paintComponent` in order to preserve the integrity of the paint chain!

Comment: *"Like I said, I'm a noob. label.setSize and setLocation were doing nothing"* - You shouldn't be using them. `JLabel` will calculate it's preferred size based on the icon and text properties and the layout manager will use this information to determine how best to layout out the component.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'll be sure to read those pages. I readded the line and did what howTo said and it also worked. My problem is solved. :)

Comment: <sigh> DON'T use `paintComponent`, `JLabel` is quite capable of showing images without your help.  You can specify anchor points (LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM, CENTER) for both the vertical and horizontal poisitions of the icon (and text) within the bounds of the component's available space through the `JLabel` itself.

Comment: I'm trying to get specific positions and sizes. Not edges or alignments. Should I use something other than JLabel?

Comment: You don't need to override `paintComponent` to define position and size of a component.  Since the question lacks context into what you are ultimately trying to do, I'd still recommend using an appropriate layout manager.  You could just use a `JPanel`, but it still begs the question of "why" do you need to do what you're trying to do?

Comment: My end goal is to make a game. These objects would be anything from pieces of the terrain to moving enemies.

I'm going to read up on paintcomponent and jpanels and labels. Thank you. :)

Comment: In that case, as a general piece of adivice, don't use Swing components.  Use a `JPanel` and perform all you painting within it's `paintComponent` method, you will generally get better performance and control

Answer (score 1):

I have no reputation for comments so i answer.

The problem is that the image in the center is the JLabel image when you create the

```
Jlabel imageLabel = new JLabel(**image**)
```

just create this without image like this

```
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(){...}
```

Comment: NO!  Don't override `paintComponent` of `JLabel` to display images, `JLabel` already displays images without your help

Comment: *"If you know an easier way to adjust the size and position of a label"* - Use an appropriate layout manager

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `paintComponent` method. You already have added your image to your label.

And you should try to avoid use code that you don't understand, or try to understand what is happening before asking, try not to say:

> I don't know how it works or why it works, but it does.

This isn't a Good Programming Practice.